# $L^1$-norm on the probability space

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, analysis, probability-distributions

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space.
Let $(g_n) \in L^2(\Omega)$ be i.i.d with $\|g_1\|_{L^2(\Omega)} = 1$.
Let $X \in L^2(\Omega)$.
Then we can expand $X$ as $X(\omega) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n g_n(\omega)$ and we have
$$
\|X\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^2. 
$$
Moreover, it is clear that
$$
\|X\|_{L^1(\Omega)} \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|.
$$
I wonder whether
$$
\|X\|_{L^1(\Omega)} \ge C \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|
$$
holds or not, where $C$ is a small constant.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO.

You have to assume that $Eg_n=0$ for all $n$ for your claim $
\|X\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^2$ to be valid.

Now, $X=\sum \frac 1 n g_n$ is a well defined $L^{2}$ random variable because $\sum \frac 1 {n^{2}}<\infty$. Hence, $X\in L^{1}$ too but $\sum \frac  1n=\infty$.